# ArcGIS Pro cannot read SQL Server databases with "-" in their name

Tags: sql-server, arcgis-pro, naming-conventions

I am using the latest ArcGIS Pro 2.2.1 and trying to use a geospatial database that is hosted in an Azure SQL Server. The issue is that ArcGIS Pro fails to query databases that have "-" in their name.

I tried with a test database and a spatial table that I called, for example, *test-geo-dataset*. I could successfully connect to the database server, select this database and see the different tables from the catalog panel. However I am unable to move data to the map. It also fails exporting data to a local geodatabase with the following error:

> ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Please refer to the error help for potential solutions, or contact Esri Technical Support http://esriurl.com/support.
>    Underlying DBMS error[[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'.]
>    Failed to execute (TableToTable).

If I rename the same database to, for example, *test_geo_dataset*, then I can drag tables to the map and export to a local geodatabase and all this works flawlessly.

I tried finding more information regarding this limitation but I cannot find if it is an ArcGIS Pro or SQL Server issue. All other SQL clients that I am using are capable of querying the *test-geo-dataset* (with "-") database. Is there a fix or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: No, this is not possible. ArcGIS requires  valid SQL standard identifiers. If  double-quotes are needed to access either table names or column names, ArcGIS woll not be able to access the data.

Comment: I believe this is a limitation of geodatabases across the board.  Same limitation exists in ArcMap.

Comment: `Some databases allow special characters such as forward slashes (/), underscores (_), dollar signs ($), dashes (-), dots (.), or mixed cases. ...
However, ArcGIS does not delimit object names. Do not create any tables, feature classes, indexes, databases, users*, roles, or other object names that require delimiters if you will be using them with ArcGIS. The object will be created in the database, but you cannot access it from ArcGIS.` https://goo.gl/PjPKm4

Comment: Perhaps ArcGIS Pro does not use delimited names when it makes the query https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/column-name-limitations?view=sql-server-2017. Without delimiters the the query means "[test] minus [geo] minus [dataset]".

Comment: Jay, please make a full answer of this documentation quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esri states this as a limitation for geodatabases on their [Enterprise geodatabase size and name limits](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/enterprise-geodatabase-limits.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_8775652F3D2E44BDB353CF9B478962BB) page.

> **Character type limits in object names**
>   Database management systems have different definitions of acceptable
>   characters for object names. Most names must begin with a letter and
>   cannot contain spaces, backslashes, or reserved database management
>   system keywords. Some databases allow special characters such as
>   forward slashes (/), underscores (_), dollar signs ($), dashes (-),
>   dots (.), or mixed cases. Sometimes the database allows you to use
>   special characters or reserved keywords, or force mixed, upper-, or
>   lowercase names if you provide the object name enclosed in delimiters,
>   such as double quotation marks.
>
> However, ArcGIS does not delimit object names. Do not create any
>   tables, feature classes, indexes, databases, users*, roles, or other
>   object names that require delimiters if you will be using them with
>   ArcGIS. The object will be created in the database, but you cannot
>   access it from ArcGIS.

I've repeatedly used mixed-case delimited by double-quote in PostgreSQL only to find out it doesn't work for ArcGIS Query Layers.  Either have to re-work the object naming in the database, or create views that aliases everything down to lower case.